# Configuration file for scons in an ubuntu system

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, scons, libstdc++

I am trying to install this tool ([ISCE](https://winsar.unavco.org/portal/wiki/Manual%20installation%20using%20repository%20managers/)) on my computer running Ubuntu 14.04.

My scons configuration file is as follows:

```
# The directory in which ISCE will be built
PRJ_SCONS_BUILD= $HOME/isce
# The directory into which ISCE will be installed
PRJ_SCONS_INSTALL= $HOME/isce
PRJ_LIB_DIR = $HOME/isce/lib
# The location of libraries, such as libstdc++, libfftw3 (for most system
# it's /usr/lib and/or /usr/local/lib/ and/or /opt/local/lib)
LIBPATH='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8'
# The location of Python.h. If you have multiple installations of python
# make sure that it points to the right one
CPPPATH='/home/shaunak/anaconda2/envs/ISCEp35/include/python3.xm'
# The location of the fftw3.h (most likely something like /usr/include or
# /usr/local/include /opt/local/include
FORTRANPATH='/usr/include'
# The location of your Fortran compiler. If not specified it will use the system one
FORTRAN='/usr/bin/gfortran'
# The location of your C compiler. If not specified it will use the system one
CC='/usr/bin'
# The location of your C++ compiler. If not specified it will use the system one
CXX='/usr/bin'
```

When I try to execute the command to install as instructed by the README: `SCONS_CONFIG_DIR=~/isce scons -Q install` it fails with the error message:

```
Error. Cannot locate the stdc++ library in the directories specified by LIBPATH in the SConfig file.
Exception: :
  File "/home/shaunak/isce/SConstruct", line 46:
    sconsConfigFile.setupScons(env,sconsSetupFile)
  File "/home/shaunak/isce/configuration/sconsConfigFile.py", line 384:
    retDict = setupCompilers(retDict)
  File "/home/shaunak/isce/configuration/sconsConfigFile.py", line 282:
    dict = setupLinux(dict)
  File "/home/shaunak/isce/configuration/sconsConfigFile.py", line 221:
    raise Exception
```

I have tried to search each library with the `locate` command and all the paths seem to be accurate. I cant seem to understand why the compilation is failing. For instance `locate libstcc++` yields:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libstdc++_pic.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libstdc++_pic.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting the project's owners and technicians about this problem? What I understand from the Overview PPT on their website is, that for the download you have already signed a license agreement. Does it contain support or maintenance? Note how this is a very specific setup, and without a lot of background infos about the build process of this project everybody else out there can only guess what's wrong. Better to ask the people that should actually *know* what's going on, right? ;)

Comment: @dirkbaechle - I did but I do not think the project is maintained regularly. I have no replies as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
LIBPATH=['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8']
```

Recall that SCons files are Python, and lists in Python are represented by `[item1, item2, ...]`.